Question about the Suzuki and Abe contour finding algorithm
Let us say that we have the following grid:
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

Then as we are following the border clockwise (say we re-label the border pixels to 2), don't we get stuck at the following point
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 2 0 0 0
0 1 1 2 0 0
0 1 1 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

We now have no 1-pixel that is unvisited in the neighborhood of the last labelled 2 here even though the border isn't finished (we haven't reached the point where we started)
Does the Suzuki-Abe algorithm account for such cases in some way?
If not, is a possible solution to keep a stack of all the visited pixels in the border so far and then retrack your steps until you find a pixel which has a next valid 1-pixel to visit in its neighborhood?

I think you got the termination condition wrong. Let P0=(1,1) be your starting point, P1=(2,1) be the second point visited. You keep following and stop the next time you arrive at P1 from P0 (meaning you went all around and started a second loop). Try it on a simple line.

Oh okay I see. But then how does the algorithm continue after (3, 4)? Does it automatically backtrack to (2, 3) - after it exhausts the new clockwise options - and continue from there?

You seem to be assuming that algorithm avoids visiting previously visited pixels.  It does not.  It treats the 2 pixels just like the 1 pixels.  It will just trace around that tail of 2s and visit them again from the bottom.
